# Getting coordinates from Path object (there are no such methods at all)

Tags: android

How do I get coordianates from [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and/or [Region](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html) objects in Android? 
There are no such methods which allow you to do that.

Basically I just need the coordinates of my figure points which my Path object contains.

Maybe I can can accomplish this via Reflection? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the source code for `Path`:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/Path.java?av=f

We can see that the coordinates are not stored on `Path` and are passed into native calls.

One workaround would be to extend `Path` and override all relevant methods (`lineTo`, `quadTo`, `moveTo`, etc.) to keep track of the coordinates yourself.

Comment: Can I somehow get coordinates from native calls? The thing is that I don't use any of the mentioned functions, so your workaround doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Maybe if you use Path's getBounds method and save result in a rect object, you can access on 'left' and 'top' property field of that object for retrieving x and y coordinates